# How to repeat columns in oracle reports just like matrix

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I want below kind of format in oracle reports 6i.

```
A  B  C     A  B  C
1  1  1     6  6  6
2  2  2     7  7  7
3  3  3     8  8  8
4  4  4     9  9  9
5  5  5     10 10 10
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h1iL.png)

Comment: You provided too few info. Example you posted doesn't look well. What are A, B and C? Columns in a table? Do they really have same values within a row? Please, post something that looks more realistic, it is difficult to guess what you really have & want.

Comment: You say you are using Oracle Reports - that has Matrix Report as an option in the create report wizard.